# Иконки на sidebar’е в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Как я могу убрать иконки на sidebar'е? Ubuntu 14.04, unity.

[screenshot sidebar](https://pp.vk.me/c630122/v630122471/22500/NfN2Lj-jH_I.jpg)

Comment: именно иконки, а не пункты? закомментируйте строки вида `icon=...` в соответствующих файлах (которые с суффиксом `.desktop`).

Comment: А где эти файлы лежат?

Comment: «везде». `$ locate -r '\.desktop$'`

Comment: их так много. подскажите какой файл может отвечать за иконки на sidebar'е.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15785171/